# How do I add a text field under the activity texarea?

Tags: plugin-development, buddypress

I am working with BuddyPress 1.7.  I need to add a text field under under the activity/update text area and capture that data when an update is posted.  Any help to help to get me started would be much appreciated.

I see the `post-form.php` file that contains the HTML form elements but how can my text box be added using a plugin through a filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add text field under the activity text area using the `bp_after_activity_post_form` hook.

```
add_action ( "bp_after_activity_post_form", 'test' );



function test()
{
    echo '<div id="tags-content"> 
            <input type="text" name="tags" value="" />
        </div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
do_action( 'bp_activity_post_form_options' )
```

hook in `post-form.php` to insert your text field.

Capture may be more difficult, but the field should be available via `$_POST`. 
Try using the `'bp_activity_before_save'` or `'bp_activity_after_save'` hooks used in `\buddypress\bp-activity\ ...php`

Comment: I'll try it ASAP and get back to you

Comment: It seems that `bp_activity_post_form_options` only gets called on group home page.